# Why does forEach, andThen require casting to Consumer?

Tags: java, list, lambda

I have an `Employee` object with an `incrementAge` method. The type of the argument to `forEach`, `Consumer< Employee>` is properly inferred with

```
emps.forEach(Employee::incrementAge);
```

However, with `.andThen`, it requires a cast. For example this will not compile:

```
emps.forEach((Employee::incrementAge).andThen(Employee::incrementAge));
```

But this will:

```
emps.forEach(((Consumer<Employee>)(Employee::incrementAge)).andThen(Employee::incrementAge));
```

Obviously I could just use `forEach` twice, but I am trying to understand how `.andThen` works.

So, am I missing something? The cast seems unnecessary.

Comment: In the second example, the type inference engine cannot infer the type of `Employee::incrementAge`.  A method reference does not have a single, inferrable type.  Rather, it can be bound to any functional interface with a compatible signature.  If the type is not known, then members like `andThen` cannot be resolved.

Comment: In your second code sample, the parentheses are incorrectly placed

Comment: @TheophileDano OP wants to invoke `Consumer#andThen` on a `Consumer<Employee>` bound to `Employee::incrementAge`.  In effect, OP wants to call `forEach(X.andThen(Y))` where `X` and `Y` are both method references, but that is simply not valid, because the compiler does not know how to infer the type of the left-hand method reference (`X`).

Comment: `.forEach()` return type is void. this isn't even valid syntax. maybe you can use `.stream()`